# Correspondance between sheaves on Étale spaces and natural transformations of sheaves.

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

If we let $\mathscr F$ be a sheaf on $X$ let $Et(\mathscr F)$ denote its Étale space over $X$. Is there a way to associate sheaves $\mathscr G$ on $Et(\mathscr F)$ to a sheaf $\mathscr G'$ on $X$ and a natural transformation $\mathscr G' \rightarrow \mathscr F$? So a functor $\text{Sh}(Et(\mathscr F)) \rightarrow \text{Sh}(X)/\mathscr F$? Let me explain what my thoughts are.

If $\mathscr G$ is a sheaf on $Et(\mathscr F)$ we can construct the Étale space of $\mathscr G$ over $Et(\mathscr F)$, $Et(\mathscr G)$. There is an Étale morphism $\phi$ given by composing $Et(\mathscr G) \rightarrow Et(\mathscr F) \rightarrow X$, then let $\mathscr G'$ denote the sheaf of local sections of $\phi$. There is a natural map $Et(\mathscr G') \xrightarrow \approx Et(\mathscr G)$ which gives a map $Et(\mathscr G') \rightarrow Et(\mathscr F)$ over $X$ and so a natural transformation $\mathscr G' \rightarrow \mathscr F$. Does this look correct? And is this a special case of some larger categorical framework?

Comment: Yes this looks correct. I want to point out that actually if $\mathcal{G}'\in\operatorname{Sh}(X)/\mathcal{F}$, then $Et(\mathcal{G}')\to Et(\mathcal{F})$ is automatically a local isomorphism, so $\mathcal{G}'$ define a sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Et(\mathcal{F})$. Thus you can show that $\operatorname{Sh}(Et(\mathcal{F}))$ is actually equivalent to $\operatorname{Sh}(X)/\mathcal{F}$ and to the category of étalé spaces over $Et(\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: Give this as an answer and I will accept it if you want the points!